# Value not changing with JavaScript ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I am attempting to change the value of an input into a different string, depending on if the inputed answer was "Yes" or "No". I have attempted to use ternary operators to clear up my code a little bit, but I keep getting original value ("Yes" or "No") instead of the value that the input should change into. I have the following code

```
function setYesNoValue(input, yes, no){
  input = input == "Yes" ? yes : no;
};
setYesNoValue(oneLInput, "517", "518");
```

The task I am attempting to perform works well when I use standard if else conditional statements, but I would like to implement this strategy to clear up the length code. Why isn't the value passed as the first argument changing when I reassign it?

Comment: Modifying the argument inside the function doesn't change the actual variable's value.

Comment: what exactly are `oneLInput` and the others? What value/reference do they contain?

Comment: Andrew is correct, the input variable is local to the function scope.